# php gaps in random() function

Tags: php, random

I would like to define gaps in `rand()` func. in Php 
The gap is like in Maths.
For example;

`$integer1= rand(1,100);` but I want to eliminate the gap between 25,60.
it is like `rand((1,25),(60,100));`
of course this notation is not acceptable by php.

Any suggestion, apart from arrays?
-Thanks

Comment: in this example you want to generate number between 1 and 100 and exclude those between 25 and 60 ?

Comment: Mohammed Yassine CHABLI yes, exactly that is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
$integer1 = rand (1, 66); // [1 .. 66]
if ($integer1 > 25) $integer1 += 34; // [1 .. 25, 60 .. 100]
```

Comment: first gap is perfect with if . but second gap should be also random. from 60 to 100.
 another if..
if ($integer1 > 25 && $integer1 < 60){....}  or else. maybe but I guess.
btw thanks.

Comment: There was only one gap in original question: [26..59].  If you need several, put use several if statatents, or, if there are a lot of gaps, use sorted arrays of them and binary search.  Let me know, if you need more detailed explanation of how to deal with lots of gaps.

Comment: This creates imbalanced probability; I do not recommend its use -- the OP did not ask for weighted randomness.

Comment: Now, my solution generates evenly distributed random number.  After the first line, all numbers in range 1..66 have the same probability.  Then I just shift some numbers not affecting their probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one cap, then @Mikhail's answer seems best choice. if you can have multiple gaps, then one variant may be:

```
$a = range(1,25);
$b =  range(60, 100); 
// add another ranges if needed
$arr = array_merge($a, $b); // merge all ranges 
echo $arr[array_rand($arr)];
```

Comment: At least do `array_rand`…!?

Comment: @deceze - Yes,  thanks, `array_rand` would be better than `shuffle`

Comment: Depends... If it's only one number you need from the array then yes array_rand is good. But if you need 10 then shuffle and array_slice.

Comment: Suggestion: https://3v4l.org/kJUOE

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make your own function but beware of the following. Each number should be drawn with equal probability. You will need to determine which range the number will actually drawn from with probability proportional to the size of the range, e.g. drawing from [1,10], [21, 40] should draw numbers from [21,40] roughly twice as frequently as from [1,10].

Here's the general idea:

Determine the length of all ranges.

Draw a random number from 0 to the length of all ranges

Check which range the number falls within.

Draw the corresponding number from the range it falls within.

```
 function randFromRanges(...$ranges) {
       $totalRangeSize = array_sum(array_map(function ($range) { 
             return $range[1] - $range[0];
       }, $ranges));
       $numberToDraw = rand(0, $totalRangeSize);
       foreach ($ranges as $range) {
            if ($numberToDraw <=  ($range[1] - $range[0])) {
                return $range[0]+$numberToDraw;
            } else {
               $numberToDraw -= ($range[1] - $range[0]);
            }
       }
   }
```

Here's a sandbox that shows that all values seem to be equi-probable:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b02603e4a9986132073d203c98f8255c2dd62e47